# How to add composite primary keys?

Tags: oracle, composite-primary-key

I have a table with three columns, [`Id,QTY,Date`]. out of these three, two columns [id and date], should be set as primary keys, because I need to fetch the record one by one, from this table, into a reference.

the data to be inserted into this table is

```
101,10,NULL    
101,20,201220    
101,7,201440    
102,5,null    
102,8,201352
```

date is in `yyyyww` format

How do I define two columns as composite primary keys when they have `null` values, duplicates?

```
alter table abc add constraint pk primary key (ID, DATE);
```

if I try to alter the table the error appears

Error report:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01449: column contains NULL values; cannot alter to NOT NULL
01449. 00000 -  "column contains NULL values; cannot alter to NOT NULL"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you think you need a primary key? Probably your concept of primary key is different than what it means in Oracle. If you want the combination of values of ID and DATE to be unique, you need a unique key.

Comment: Can I add one primary and two unique keys... does unique key allow multiple nulls and duplicates????

Comment: The word unique means, the column value must be unique and it cannot allow duplicates. Try reading about constraint and keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column name of your table is ID and it is still null and non-unique, how is it possible. If it is primary key of other table try adding a **surrogate key** column for this table and make it primary key.

In case of composite primary key, it should have atleast one not null value(For each row) in the combination of columns. And the combination of column must be unique at all case.

For further details check, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c22integ.htm

**Correction** - If composite primary key is made up of 3 columns, then no column (among 3) can hold NULL value. And the combination of those 3 columns must be unique. 
E.g. (1,2,2)
        (1,2,1)
        (2,2,1)
        (1,2,2) - not valid

Comment: Can u ply explain in detail how to alter a table with Id alone as as PK, to include the following data....     1) i should alter the structure of the table to include another column     2) I should do something to make it accept the following data 101,10,NULL     101,20,201220     101,7,201440     102,5,null     102,8,201352         3) I must be able to fetch values from this based on id, date.

Comment: A column to be added as primary key must be unique, each row should have different not null value. Major purpose of primary key is to make a row identifiable with  a single column in the row. So if you need a PK, try creating ur own column which will have unique value in each row. In your case you could create a column s_id and create a sequence and link to it.

Answer (score 3):

Using table level constraint, you can use this query

```
alter table your_table add constraint pkc_Name primary key (column1, column2)
```

but first you need to declare the columns `NOT NULL`. All parts of a primary key need to be `NOT NULL`.